# Apple Maps: Renaming Favorites or Marked Locations

Tags: ios, maps, macos

There must be some really obvious trick which has escaped me.

If I favorite a marked location on MacOS Maps, or on iOS Maps, I can’t see how I can give it a custom name.

Tapping or clicking on Info doesn’t seem to help, and I can’t see any other method.

I have tried the technique of selecting favorites from the search bar (in MacOS), selecting edit and trying, but the text remains uneditable.

I would even consider a third party app if there is one.

I am using MacOS Mojave, and iOS 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rename favorites in Maps on macOS ([source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7904987)):

1. Click on the magnifying glass in the search field
2. Click Favorites
3. Click "Edit" in the bottom right
4. Click on a Favorite's name to modify it
5. Press return or click out of the editing field, then click "Done"

To rename favorites in Maps on iOS:

1. Swipe up the "card" at the bottom that contains recent locations
2. Scroll to the bottom and tap on "Favorites"
3. Swipe from right to left across the favorite whose name you want to change, then tap "Edit Name"
4. Enter a new name, then tap "Save"

I've tried both of these methods on macOS 10.14.2 and iOS 12.1.2 and confirmed that they both work.

Comment: It doesn’t seem to work for all pins, such as those added in response to a search. Thanks for the answer. I don’t think either of them is intuitive.

Comment: @Manngo I think the issue with certain search results is that if you're favoriting a location that has information listed with Apple Maps (e.g., a business), that information (controlled by Apple, not you) is pulled into your Favorites list. Notice that if you search for a residential address and favorite it from the search, you can still change the name.

Comment: I can’t make any sense out of these instructions in iOS 1.3.  “Favorites” is an unclickable label, with a row of round buttons below it,  There’s no way to pick one and swipe left on it.

Comment: @JWWalker you need to tap "See All" next to the "Favorites" label, tap the "ⓘ" button, and change the label on the screen that appears. But my answer specifically states that it is relevant only through iOS 12; Apple redesigned Maps in iOS 13.

Comment: @aaplmath, thanks, that works.  Yes, I knew your answer didn’t claim to address iOS 13.  But now, with this info in the comments, it’s even better.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to reproduce the broken icon buttons in Maps *v3.0 (2684.21.9.22.1)* on MacOS Monterey *v12.0 (21A5543b)*

The info button stops working for favorites if a user clicks *any* favorite info icon when *any* callout is open on the map.

Bug report: FB9754165 submitted: 12-Nov-21

**Fix:** restart Maps and ensure no callouts (pin details, user details, etc..) are open on the map when clicking an info icon.